# Strange implications with $aN$, $eF$ and $gH$

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

Given the implications

> $$aN\implies S$$ $$eF\implies I$$ $$gH\implies M$$

could you please complete the following implication:

> $$nS\implies ?$$

(The answer is one of the letters $T$, $A$, $L$, $K$.)

Comment: Hm, I could've sworn I've seen this before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> T

Justification:

> The puzzle is built around the periodic system of chemical elements:
>
>  Na = Sodium  (Na reflected = aN; first letter of Sodium = S)
>  Fe = Iron  (Fe reflected = eF; first letter of Iron = I)
>  Hg = Mercury  (Hg reflected = gH; first letter of Mercury = M)
>  Sn = Tin  (Sn reflected = nS; first letter of Tin = T)